# Find the sum of two numbers without using any operators

Tags: c

In an interview, I was asked to write a C program to find the sum of two numbers without using any operators. I think it can be done using the return value of `printf`, but I don't see how to do this.

Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without using any operator?" Are you completely prohibited from using any operators at all, or are you just supposed to not use +?

Comment: "find sum of two numbers without using any operator" - Even "paper + pencil" or "paper & pencil" has an operator...

Comment: You can't use any kind of operator.

Comment: It has to do something with the return type of printf.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to ask this in the CodeGolf sister site.

Comment: I am wondering from that day...i am not able to figure it out..k i will post it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an awful interview question. Really. It doesn't assess any relevant skills at all.

That said, here's the answer:

```
int n1 = /* ... */;
int n2 = /* ... */
int sum = printf("%*s%*s", n1, "", n2, "");
```

The `%*s` in `printf` means "print a string, but make the minimum number of characters printed equal to the value passed in as an argument." This works by printing out `n1` characters, then `n2` characters, and using the fact that `printf` returns the total number of characters printed. The `printf` will always print exactly `n1 + n2` characters, since the empty string has length 0 and thus the maximum padding will always be used. This is perhaps the worst possible way I can think of to add numbers - the runtime is Θ(n1 + n2) and in the process, it prints out a gazillion blanks to the screen.

But yeah. This is an awful interview question and you should have serious concerns about working at a place that is giving this as an interview question. Something is seriously up with their hiring process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks dude..it really help me out...but i am not getting one thing, why you have used that double quotes.

Comment: @suryasingh `%*s` means "print out the string passed in as a parameter, setting the width to be at least the length of the parameter before it." We therefore need to specify both a length parameter (n1 or n2) and the string to print (here, `""`).

Comment: @suryasingh If you don't, then read the manual of `printf()` and you will.

Comment: what happens if you add 0 and 5 for instance?

Comment: @KeithNicholas- By my understanding, using `%*s` here will try to print the empty string (zero characters), padded up to a minimum of n1 (0) characters in length. That means that the first print operation will print no characters at all. Is that correct?

Comment: What happens if one of the numbers is negative

Comment: @waTeim That's a good point. I assumed the inputs were nonnegative integers, but if they're negative this won't work.

Comment: My understanding is that `printf` is a functional call, and a function call is itself an operator (the function call operator), which means no using `printf`. This is a pretty silly question if you can call arbitrary functions that do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a trick question to get you to write a program that asks the user to input the answer and then display it.

Comment: I don't know of a way in C to get a number from the user without using the address-of operator `&` as part of `scanf`. Can you show how you'd do this without using any operators?

Comment: @templatetypedef `char line[LINE_MAX]; fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin); int number = strtol(line, NULL, 10);` - you shouldn't even be thinking about `scanf()` at all, it's awful.

Comment: @H2CO3- Good point. I was thinking that `=` counted as an operator.

Comment: @templatetypedef: `int number[1]; scanf("%d", number);`. But I agree that scanf is not necessarily the best tool. (Also, IMHO function call is an operator. It certainly is in C++.)

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = 4, b = 5, sum;
FILE * f=fopen("tmp","w");

char *buf_a = calloc(a,1);
char *buf_b = calloc(b,1);
fwrite(buf_a,a,1,f);
fwrite(buf_b,b,1,f);
sum = ftell (f);

printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, sum);
```

Comment: `=` in that assignment isn't an operator?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 11;
    int y = 22;
    int sum = printf("%*c%*c",  x, ' ',  y, ' ');
    printf("Sum = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't this work incorrectly if `x` or `y` is 0? Also, isn't this pretty much my solution?

Comment: you are right, if x or y is 0, it won't work, but as you said this is an awful interview question, no one would want to use this for adding two numbers, I guess the point here is to know the return value of printf

Answer (score -1):

Using Logrithimic and exponential function inside printf, we can perform sum of two numbers

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

 
int main(void)
{
    int a = 8, b = 6;
 
    printf("%g\n", log(exp(a) * exp(b)));
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The puzzle was not, "Add two numbers without using the `+` operator".  It was, "Add two numbers without using *any* operators".  But `*` is an operator.

Comment: log(ab) can be refered as log(a*b)

Comment: Yes, in mathematics, multiplication is implied, so *a b* means *a* × *b*.  But in C, `exp(a) exp(b)` is a syntax error, and will not even compile.  Your edit made your answer worse.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x, y, sum;
    x = 10, y = 5;
    sum = printf("%*c%*c", x, ' ', y, ' ');

    printf("Sum of x and y is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer add anything that the other answers don't already say?

Comment: Yes you got it right. The exact answer was already there but I just noticed it.